# Macbook Snow Leopard Unzipped file

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, snow-leopard

I used Terminal command to unzip an audio file downloaded from a public library.  Command used: `unzip -v /<zip filename.zip>; rm -rf _MACOSX`.  Terminal displayed 31 files were extracted and stored. I used both Search in Finder and Go to Folder to find the files and only 1 pdf file was found.  The other 30 files, all mp3, went missing.

I noticed that the more than 1gb of disk space was gone.  So I assume the files are residing somewhere.  Could anyone please help.  Many thanks!

Comment: Try executing the command *without* the `; rm -rf _MACOSX` and see if that helps.

Comment: You can view the files inside the archive with- `unzip -l filename.zip`. That should give you an indication of where the files are. They should be in the directory in which you uncompressed the archive.

Answer (score 1):

The unix command to search for files is `find`.

You can use the command `man find` to get more information. The usual form is the following.

```
find  <starting folder>  -name  <file name>  -print
```

For example, if you are looking for all `mp3` files in the current folder and all nested folders, use the following command.

```
find  .  -name  "*.mp3"  -print
```

Sometimes you can get a lot of "permission denied" or other meaningless error messages. If so, then you can remove ***all*** error messages by appending a `2>/dev/null` to the end of the command. See the example below.

```
find  .  -name  "*.mp3"  -print  2>/dev/null
```